# Modal in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pdo, bootstrap-modal

How can I show a modal (VIEW.BLADE.PHP), which depends on the CRUD of Laravel?

VIEW.BLADE.PHP:

```
<div class="black-balloon to-close" id="messages-balloon">
    <h1 class="title"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Minhas mensagens</h1>

    <i id="close-balloon" class="fa fa-times" style="color:#fff"></i>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="public/uploads/users/rosana.jpg">
            <h1>Rosana Teves</h1>
            <h3><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>há 2 horas</h3>

            <h2>Olá filho, você é o melhor cara!</h2>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Load the modal (VIEW.BLADE.PHP):

```
<button class="logged-actions-btn" title="Messages" onclick="load_balloon('header/messages-balloon')"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></button>

function load_balloon(patch,id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../resources/Views/balloons/' + patch + '.blade.php',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        beforeSend: function () {
               $(".to-hide").hide();
               $(".to-close").remove();

            if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
               $(".header").css("z-index","1002");
               $("#header-mobile-menu-icon").removeClass('fa-arrow-left');
               $("#header-mobile-menu-icon").addClass('fa-bars');
            }

            $(".shadow").show();
            $('#loading-balloon').show();

             block_scroll();
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("body").append(response);
            $('#loading-balloon').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Controller.php

> ?????????

Model.php

```
     $links = DB::table('messages')
    ->join('users', 'users.UserId', '=', 'messages.UserId')
    ->select('messages.*', 'users.UserName')
    ->get();
```

Comment: don't add lorem ipsum to fill in words , instead try to explain your problem . There is a reason why you have to write a minimum of words

Answer (score 0):

According to bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-options) on javascript modal

> This option is deprecated since v3.3.0 and has been removed in v4. We
>   recommend instead using client-side templating or a data binding
>   framework, or calling jQuery.load yourself.
>
> If a remote URL is provided, content will be loaded one time via
>   jQuery's load method and injected into the .modal-content div. If
>   you're using the data-api, you may alternatively use the href
>   attribute to specify the remote source. An example of this is shown
>   below:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```

If your version is version then drop the comment so i update the answer

Thanks.